# LDAP: Find the DistinguishedName (DN) from the userPrincipalName (UPN) in AD with openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to get ldapwhoami (OpenLDAP on linux) to report the DN when I bind to an AD server with a UPN. All I can seem to get back is the domain and the user. I would use ldapsearch, but I don't know the base (-b option) to start from. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
$ ldapwhoami -D "userX@Example.com" -w "xyz" -p 389 -h xx.xx.xx.xx 
u:DOMAIN\userX
```

Comment: You can try to get a top-level base dn by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230134/how-can-you-view-what-roots-are-available-in-a-unix-ldap-database/47239911#47239911), then you would be able to use ldapsearch with the -b option.

Comment: @EricLavault I appreciate the answer and that's definitely a fallback option. My only hesitation is that starting the search at the root may be time consuming for large directories. It sure seems like ldapwhoami has done the hard work by setting up the session and the info about the connection user should be readily available (I would imagine).

Comment: Yes for sure. To go futher, once you get some entries from a search, you can check for example if all user entries share the same *base* like `ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`, then you would be able to refine the base dn according to this conclusion. You can also use filter like `objectClass=user`.