# How to fix authentication finally failed (Ldap)

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, ldap, openldap, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm working with opendistro and i'm using security plugin
I'm using docker and im trying to connect to ldap, but i got this error:

```
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T10:25:14,609][WARN ][c.a.d.a.l.b.LDAPAuthorizationBackend] [922e43c02326] Unable to connect to ldapserver example.com:389 due to [org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException@1629074075::resultCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, message=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out], providerException=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]. Try next.
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T10:25:14,615][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [922e43c02326] Authentication finally failed for admin from 172.23.0.2:52408
```

I've tried to change /ect/hosts but nothing could work

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2.2'
    services:
      openldap:
        image: osixia/openldap:1.2.4
        container_name: openldap
        environment:
          LDAP_LOG_LEVEL: "256"
          LDAP_ORGANISATION: "Example Inc"
          LDAP_DOMAIN: "example.com"
          LDAP_BASE_DN: "dc=example,dc=com"
          LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: XXXX
          LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD: "config"
          LDAP_READONLY_USER: "false"
          LDAP_READONLY_USER_USERNAME: "readonly"
          LDAP_READONLY_USER_PASSWORD: "readonly"
          LDAP_RFC2307BIS_SCHEMA: "false"
          LDAP_BACKEND: "mdb"
          LDAP_TLS: "true"
          LDAP_TLS_CRT_FILENAME: "ldap.crt"
          LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILENAME: "ldap.key"
          LDAP_TLS_CA_CRT_FILENAME: "ca.crt"
          LDAP_TLS_ENFORCE: "false"
          LDAP_TLS_PROTOCOL_MIN: "3.1"
          LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT: "demand"
          LDAP_REPLICATION: "false"
          KEEP_EXISTING_CONFIG: "false"
          LDAP_REMOVE_CONFIG_AFTER_SETUP: "true"
          LDAP_SSL_HELPER_PREFIX: "ldap"
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/ldap
          - /etc/ldap/slapd.d
          - /container/service/slapd/assets/certs/
        ports:
          - "389:389"
          - "636:636"
        domainname: "example.com" # important: same as hostname
        hostname: "example.com"
   networks:
            esnet
      phpldapadmin:
        image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
        container_name: phpldapadmin
        environment:
          PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS: "openldap"
          PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS: "false"
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        depends_on:
          - openldap
        networks:
            esnet
      elasticsearch:
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.0.2
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
          - cluster.name=docker-cluster
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true  # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
          - discovery.type=single-node
          - OPENSSL_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/bin
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          #- ./cert/truststore.jks:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/truststore.jks
          # - ./elasticsearch/config/action_groups.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml:ro
          # - ./elasticsearch/config/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml:ro
          - ./elasticsearch/config/roles_mapping.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles_mapping.yml.yml:ro
          # - ./elasticsearch/config/roles.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles.yml:ro
          - ./elasticsearch/config/config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml:rw
          - ./elasticsearch/security.sh:/usr/share/elasticsearch/security.sh
          # ./elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        ports:
        - "9300:9300"
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9600:9600" 
        networks:
            esnet:
              aliases:
              - node-0.example.com
        healthcheck:
          test: if [[ $$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' https://elasticsearch:9200 -u admin:admin --insecure ) == 200 ]]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
          interval: 30s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 100
        user: root
```

Here's config.yml

```
_meta:
  type: "config"
  config_version: 2

config:
  dynamic:
    # Set filtered_alias_mode to 'disallow' to forbid more than 2 filtered aliases per index
    # Set filtered_alias_mode to 'warn' to allow more than 2 filtered aliases per index but warns about it (default)
    # Set filtered_alias_mode to 'nowarn' to allow more than 2 filtered aliases per index silently

    http:
      anonymous_auth_enabled: false
      xff:
        enabled: false
doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve
    authc:
      ldap:
        description: "Authenticate via LDAP or Active Directory"
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 1
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:

          type: ldap
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            pemtrustedcas_filepath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/root-ca.pem
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
            - "openldap"

            bind_dn: "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" 
            password: XXXX
            userbase: 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'

            username_attribute: null
    authz:
      roles_from_myldap:
        description: "Authorize via LDAP or Active Directory"
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
          type: ldap
          config:

            enable_ssl: false
            pemtrustedcas_filepath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/root-ca.pem

            enable_start_tls: false

            enable_ssl_client_auth: false

            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
            - openldap

            bind_dn: null
            password: null
            rolebase: 'ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'


            rolesearch: '(member={0})'

            userroleattribute: null

            userrolename: disabled
          Default is "name".
           resolve_nested_roles: true
            userbase: 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'

            usersearch: '(uid={0})'

      roles_from_another_ldap:
        description: "Authorize via another Active Directory"
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
          type: ldap
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue
thank you,
best regards

This Is the error i et after having changed BASEDN

```
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:58:47,908][WARN ][c.a.d.a.l.b.LDAPAuthorizationBackend] [2219e2665aec] Unable to connect to ldapserver example.com due to [org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException@303672734::resultCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, message=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out], providerException=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]. Try next.
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:58:47,911][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [2219e2665aec] Authentication finally failed for admin from 192.168.32.2:51676
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:59:23,799][WARN ][c.a.d.a.l.b.LDAPAuthorizationBackend] [2219e2665aec] Unable to connect to ldapserver example.com due to [org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException@846396247::resultCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, message=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out], providerException=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]. Try next.
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:59:23,800][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [2219e2665aec] Authentication finally failed for admin from 192.168.32.2:51680
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:59:39,329][ERROR][c.a.o.s.s.h.n.OpenDistroSecuritySSLNettyHttpServerTransport] [2219e2665aec] SSL Problem Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
elasticsearch    | javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:672) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:627) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:443) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:422) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634) ~[?:?]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295) ~[netty-handler-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1301) ~[netty-handler-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203) ~[netty-handler-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247) ~[netty-handler-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502) ~[netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441) ~[netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278) ~[netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:556) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:510) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470) [netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909) [netty-common-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
elasticsearch    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:59:59,696][WARN ][c.a.d.a.l.b.LDAPAuthorizationBackend] [2219e2665aec] Unable to connect to ldapserver example.com due to [org.ldaptive.provider.ConnectionException@142684755::resultCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, message=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out], providerException=javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]. Try next.
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T11:59:59,705][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [2219e2665aec] Authentication finally failed for admin from 192.168.32.2:51702
```

**UPDATE**

i've fixed unable to connect to openldap by changing the hostname in example.com:389 in config.yml and by change the name of the docker container in example.com

I put here new docker-compose:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  example.com:
    image: osixia/openldap:1.2.4
    container_name: example.com
    environment:
      #LDAP_ORGANISATION: # Organisation name. Defaults to Example Inc.
      LDAP_DOMAIN: example.com #Ldap domain. Defaults to example.org
      LDAP_BASE_DN: "" #Ldap base DN. If empty automatically set from LDAP_DOMAIN value. Defaults to (empty)
      #LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD Ldap Admin password. Defaults to admin
    ports:
      - "389:389"
      - "636:636"
    networks: 
      - esnet
  phpldapadmin:
    image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
    container_name: phpldapadmin
    environment:
      PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS: "example.org"
      PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS: "false"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - example.com
    networks: 
      - esnet
  elasticsearch:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.0.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true  # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 
    networks:
      esnet:
        aliases:
        - node-0.example.com
  kibana:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.0.2
    container_name: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
    ports: 
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://elasticsearch:9200
    networks: 
      - esnet
```

new config.yml (passwords are just for testing)

```
_meta:
  type: "config"
  config_version: 2

config:
  dynamic:
    http:
      anonymous_auth_enabled: false
      xff:
        enabled: false
        internalProxies: '192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.11' # regex pattern

    authc:
      basic_internal_auth_domain:
        description: "Authenticate via HTTP Basic against internal users database"
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        order: 4
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          type: intern
      ldap:
        description: "Authenticate via LDAP or Active Directory"
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 5
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: true
        authentication_backend:
          # LDAP authentication backend (authenticate users against a LDAP or Active Directory)
          type: ldap
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
            - example.com:389
            bind_dn: "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
            password: "admin"
            userbase: 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'
            # Filter to search for users (currently in the whole subtree beneath userbase)
            # {0} is substituted with the username
            usersearch: '(sAMAccountName={0})'
            # Use this attribute from the user as username (if not set then DN is used)
            username_attribute: null
    authz:
      roles_from_myldap:
        description: "Authorize via LDAP or Active Directory"
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
          # LDAP authorization backend (gather roles from a LDAP or Active Directory, you have to configure the above LDAP authentication backend settings too)
          type: ldap
          config:
            # enable ldaps
            enable_ssl: false
            # enable start tls, enable_ssl should be false
            enable_start_tls: false
            # send client certificate
            enable_ssl_client_auth: false
            # verify ldap hostname
            verify_hostnames: true
            hosts:
            - localhost:8389
            bind_dn: null
            password: null
            rolebase: 'ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'
            # Filter to search for roles (currently in the whole subtree beneath rolebase)
            # {0} is substituted with the DN of the user
            # {1} is substituted with the username
            # {2} is substituted with an attribute value from user's directory entry, of the authenticated user. Use userroleattribute to specify the name of the attribute
            rolesearch: '(member={0})'
            # Specify the name of the attribute which value should be substituted with {2} above
            userroleattribute: null

            userrolename: disabled

            resolve_nested_roles: true
            userbase: 'ou=people,dc=example,dc=com'

      roles_from_another_ldap:
        description: "Authorize via another Active Directory"
        http_enabled: false
        transport_enabled: false
        authorization_backend:
          type: ldap
```

but i get a new error:

```
  elasticsearch    | [2019-07-31T12:48:42,590][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [28da1860f0c0] Authentication finally failed for cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com from 192.168.64.1:58682
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-31T12:48:43,430][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [28da1860f0c0] Authentication finally failed for kibanaserver from 192.168.64.2:39506
```

if i try to query this :

```
docker exec example.com ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w admin
```

i get:

```
extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example.com
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example

# admin, example.com
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9QnJDbHdTYnRRb3dHazJiQlB6MTF3R29MS3dFVmxmZUk=

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntries: 2
```

This is my kibana.yml

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: https://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]
opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
```

It from here that it takes kibanaserver user

do you guys have any hint? Which credentials should i use to log in?
thank you all for your replies!

Comment: Start by setting a base dn, eg. if host/domain name is 'example.com', set `LDAP_BASE_DN : "dc=example,dc=com"`. Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47230134/2529954) to know how to get valid top-level base dn(s).

Comment: Hi thank for replying, i changed BASE DN and im getting the same error and a new one

Comment: Can you `telnet example.com 389` successfully` ? This line is interesting `SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown` though I'm not sure I can help..

Comment: telnet example.com 389
Trying 93.184.216.34...
Trying 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable


mmm...im using opendistro certificates...

Comment: ... :/ maybe you will have more hints on serverfault ?

Comment: I could make it work, i only have one error now, which is:
elasticsearch    | [2019-07-29T13:44:43,412][WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [afa027768ec9] Authentication finally failed for admin from 172.26.0.2:52254

do you have any hints?

Comment: I think that in the `hosts:` parts of config.yml (authc & authz), you should replace `- "openldap"` by `- example.com:389`. What is the output of `ldapsearch -x -H 'ldap://example.com:389' -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -b ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` ?

Comment: i fixed this by putting what you said and by calling the docker container example.com

I get a new error now: Unable to connect to ldapserver example.com:389 due to [org.ldaptive.LdapException@576732372::resultCode=INVALID_CREDENTIALS, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, message=javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials], providerException=javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]]. Try next.

and if query ldap using ldapsearch iit says ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Comment: Ok, "Invalid credentials" means the provided password or the bind dn `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com` is wrong, I can't help for this but you need to use a manager account. Once you get to bind with `ldapsearch` cmd, update the configuration file accordingly. It's a general tip : always test ldap bindings or read access etc. with the simplest and most straight forward tool that is `ldapsearch`, then you can tweak config files with a bit more confidence.