# Django - Ldap setting issue

Tags: django, ldap, django-settings, django-ldapdb

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config 
import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType
```

**Baseline configuration.**

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://sub.domain.com'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'CN=Bind Account,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'passwrd'

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'OU=XXX,DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(uid=%(user)s)',
)

AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,OU=XXX,DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com"

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_BASE = "OU=XXX,DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com"

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER = 'member={0}'
```

**Set up the basic group parameters.**

```
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_BASE,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER,
)

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr='CN')
```

**Simple group restrictions**

```
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = 'CN=enabled,OU=XXX,OU=groups,DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com'

AUTH_LDAP_DENY_GROUP = 'CN=disabled,OU=XXX,OU=groups,DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com'
```

**Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.**

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    'first_name': 'givenName',
    'last_name': 'sn',
    'email': 'mail',
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    'is_active': 'CN=Bind Account,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com',
    'is_staff': 'CN=Bind Account,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com',
    'is_superuser': 'CN=Bind Account,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com',
}
```

**view.py**

```
user_obj = authenticate(request, username='userid', password='passwrd')
user_detail = login(request, user_obj, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

I'm getting the below error,
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

I tried the below code also,

```
conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://sub.domain.com')
result = conn.search_s('CN=Bind Account,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectClass=*)')
```

For the above code, I got a different error,

```
NO_SUCH_OBJECT at /
{'msgtype': 101, 'msgid': 1, 'result': 32, 'desc': 'No such object', 'ctrls': [], 'matched': 'DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com', 'info': "0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03152973, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:\n\t'DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com'\n"}
```

Comment: It looks like your domain components (`dc`'s) are wrong: for the bind dn you set `DC=ad,DC=users,DC=com` while the user dn template takes `DC=users,DC=yyy,DC=com`. If it's the case you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47239911/2529954) for getting valid top-level base dn(s).

Comment: Now I'm getting below error:
is_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group_dn' while authenticating

Comment: AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_BASE = "OU=xxx,DC=ad,DC=acc,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER = '(objectClass=groupOfNames)' #'(member={0})'

# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_BASE,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER,
)

Comment: Please update yout post to mention the error and the setttings you tried.